# Python regex for detecting all the urls excluding certain domains

Tags: python, regex, url

I have this python regex that detects all urls:

```
r'(http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+)'
```

But I need to exclude youtube and vimeo url from the detection. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
(http[s]?://(?!youtube|vimeo)(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+)
```

See demo [https://regex101.com/r/jB7tN3/1](https://regex101.com/r/jB7tN3/2)